# gradlew testDebugUnitTest mergeAndroidReports

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

It's of my understanding that for running only the unit tests following is used:

```
gradlew testDebugUnitTest
```

This also works and report gets generated, but if I write following:

```
gradlew testDebugUnitTest mergeAndroidReports
```

I get:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:connectedDebugAndroidTest'.
> com.android.builder.testing.api.DeviceException: No connected devices!
```

So it's trying to also run the instrumentation tests, is this supposed to be expected or is this a bug?

Seen on Android Studio 4 Canary 9 with latest gradle version (4.0.0-alpha09).

[mergeAndroidReports](https://developer.android.com/studio/test/command-line#multi-module-reports)

Comment: Hey, David, did you find a way to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

`mergeAndroidReports` appears to only merge the test reports generated by the instrumentation `androidTest` tests, which is why the task depends on `connectedAndroidTest`.